# Can I have 2 different DNs zones?

Tags: wordpress, ruby-on-rails-3, dns, heroku

I have a wordpress blog hosted on blog.company.com, and now I'm trying to create a DNS entry on Heroku to get mycompany.com but I get the following error:

!   could not create zone; already registered on Zerigo to a different account?

What am I missing herE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess there's already an account on Zerigo that has the zone mycompany.com registered to it.

You can't (easily) have a domain hosted on two seperate DNS providers, you're best option would be to find the DNS host of blog.mycompany.com and setup a subdomain on the mycompany.com domain, eg www as a cname entry to proxy.heroku.com and then add www.mycompany.com as a custom domain on your heroku application.

The fact that you're getting the message about a duplicate zone, is Zerigo already hosting the DNS for blog.company.com perhaps? In which case login to the control panel for that (the zone is company.com) and add a record for your site.